# Using PhoneGap Build

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, cordova, mobile

I started developing for mobile devices. I want to use PhoneGap but without any IDE just with creating www folder, uploading it on build.phonegap.com and have fun. So my question is if you can list all the files from the phonegap downloaded folder I must include in my www projecct folder and describe me what to include in the html file and where to put my other .js files. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/preparing-your-app) is pretty clear on what to include/exclude, where to put things.